# Blocking Visitors Referred From Indicated Domains

Tags: .htaccess, http-referer, referer

I'm trying to block visitors if they are from certain referers via .htaccess (Apache).

Found this code and variants multiple places on the web, but it seems to block all traffic, instead of just the referring domains:

```
# block visitors referred from indicated domains
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sweetfreestuff.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} wormhole.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
</ifModule>
```

Also have tried this variation, with no change:

```
# block visitors referred from indicated domains
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sweetfreestuff\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} wormhole\.com [NC,OR]
 RewriteRule .* - [F]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Don't you need a back slash before .com? (http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml) I guess I've never tried it without... And a # Options +FollowSymlinks before RewriteCond?

Comment: I've tried with and without the slashes.

Comment: Hmm, if you're getting a 500 error try commenting +FollowSyslinks. And make sure the <IfModule bit isn't doing the opposite of what it's meant to. Other than that I'm not seeing it. I use a similar piece of code without issue...

Comment: @lostphilosopher +FollowSyslinks being there or not didn't make any difference. I also tried without the IfModule. Still no luck. I ended up going a slightly more verbose way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another route to go.. still .htaccess, but a different syntax that separates out the testing of the referrer from the forbidding of the referrer.

```
# Deny access to all with status "banned"
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://([a-z0-9\-]+\.)?sweetfreestuff\.com.*$" banned

# Enable Rewrite mode
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# 301-Redirect to themselves
RewriteCond %{ENV:banned} ^1$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)$

# In any case => 403-Forbidden Page
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=banned
```